# How to display posts with plugin (advanced custom fields) field groups?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, advanced-custom-fields

I have a **php/wordpress** code (present inside **abc.php file**) as shown  below which displays images of particular size.

**php/wordpress:**

```
<ul id="list-thumbs" class="list-grid">
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="list-grid__thumb shows-grid__item">
                    <a class="list-grid__img-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>" tabindex="0">
                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <?php
                            $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
                            WORLD\Images\the_img_fit_figure( $image_id, 'list-grid__image', '(min-width: 450px) 50vw, 70vw', false ); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>

        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

The code above displays around 30-40 images from top to bottom with 4 images in one row.

**(a)** **All of those images are featured image in wordpress associated with a post.**

**(b)** Every post has two fields, **Row View (in_row_view)** and **Column View (in_column_view)** coming from Advanced Custom Fields plug in. I am not sure if we can call those two fields as custom fields.

**(c)** **Row View** and **Column View** both are switch which can be enabled to **Yes** or **No**. By default it is set to **No**.

**(d)** For Row View, I am using:

```
if(get_field('in_row_view' ) == '1'){   }
```

For Column View, I am using:

```
if( get_field('in_column_view' ) == '1'){   }
```

What I want to achieve is I want to display those posts which have **Row View** switch enabled to **Yes**.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the php/wordpress code above so that it displays only those posts which have **Row View** switch enabled to **Yes**.

Probably I need to integrate this code `if(get_field('in_row_view' ) == '1'){   }` in the `php/wordpress` code above.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to create a custom `WP_Query`. What you would do is something like this (modified from ACF documentation):

```php
<?php

    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'in_row_view',
                'value' => '1',
            )
        )
    ) );

    if( $posts ) {
        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            // Do something.
       }
    }
```

So, in your code, you will not use the base `while(have_posts())` loop but a loop iterating the post (the `foreach` in my example).